# How to exclude certain items from query ordering but still keep them in the query in Django?

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to send a list of IDs to my API of items which should always appear at the top of the query disregarding the ordering.
For example, if I send `ids=3,4` to the API and I have 5 objects in the DB and I order by `created_at`, I would like to receive them in order: `3 4 1 2 5` or if I order by `-created_at` then `3 4 5 2 1`.

I tried to do this

```
# Apply the default ordering first
queryset = super().filter_queryset(request, queryset, view)
if "ids" in request.query_params:
   first_ids = request.query_params["ids"].split(",")
queryset = queryset.order_by(Case(When(id__in=first_ids, then=0), default=1))
return queryset
```

This works when I order by `created_at` for example, but fails for `-created_at`.

Comment: a) it smells like a classic [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - what you're trying to do is unclear; may be it's better to do _such things_ in a different way b) there is no attempt to sort by either `created_at` or `-created_at` in the shown code which means that the solution includes somewhat surrounding code which makes even _the how_ you're trying to do _it_ unclear too. Please describe the original need and provide "minimal repro/demo" of the complete scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to annotate all items to split them to two groups. Then you can sort by two fields, first by annotated field then by 'created_at'. So your code should be like this:

```
queryset = super().filter_queryset(request, queryset, view)
if "ids" in request.query_params:
   first_ids = request.query_params["ids"].split(",")
queryset = queryset.annotate(ids=Case(When(id__in=first_ids, then=Value(0)), default=1, output_field=models.IntegerField())).order_by('ids', 'created_at')
return queryset
```